# Error: addTodo() method does not exist - why does it throw this error?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I've been staring at this for hours but I don't understand what's wrong with it. It just tells me that the addTodo method doesn't exist when I've defined it in the controller file - what am I missing here?

**main.js**

```
angular.module('mytodoApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, localStorageService) {
    //  breaks on repeat or blank input
    function addTodoFn() {
        $scope.todos.push($scope.todo); 
        $scope.todo = '';   
    }

    function removeTodoFn(index) {
        $scope.todos.splice(index, 1);
    }

    function watchFn() {
      localStorageService.set('todos', $scope.todos);
    }

    //////////

    var todosInStore = localStorageService.get('todos');
    $scope.todos = todosInStore || [];
    $scope.$watch('todos', watchFn, true);
    $scope.addTodo = addTodoFn;
    $scope.removeTodo = removeTodoFn;
  });
```

**main.spec.js**

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {
  var MainCtrl;
  var scope;
  var store = [];
  var todo;
  var localStorage = { 
    addItem: function() {
      store.push(todo);
    }, 
    deleteItem: function(index) {
      store.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('mytodoApp');
  });

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl as mc', {
      $scope: scope
    });

    // LocalStorage mock.
    spyOn(MainCtrl, 'addTodo').and.callFake(localStorage.addItem); <-- throwing the error
    spyOn(MainCtrl, 'removeTodo').and.callFake(localStorage.deleteItem);
  })); 

  afterEach(function() {
    store = [];
    todo = '';
  });

  it('should have no items to start with', function() {
    expect(store.length).toBe(0);
  });

  it('should add items to the list', function() {
    todo = 'a';
    scope.addTodo();
    expect(store.length).toBe(1);

    todo = 'b';
    scope.addTodo();
    expect(store.length).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

**Error**

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Controller: MainCtrl should add items to the list FAILED
>
> Error: addTodo() method does not exist at /Users/Baggio/mytodo/test/spec/controllers/main.js:29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're spying the `addTodo` method of `MainCtrl`. But `MainCtrl` doesn't have such a method. The method is on the `scope`, not on `MainCtrl`.

BTW, if you spied on scope, your test would test anything: it would only test that the Jasmin spy does what it's supposed to do, instead of testing that the actual addTodo() method does what it's supposed to do. What you should be spying or mocking are the *dependencies* of the controller, i.e. the localStorage service.

Comment: Wow - replaced MainCtrl with scope and green lights when the tests ran. But I'm a little confused by your statement - "what you should be spying or mocking are the dependencies of the controller" - my interpretation of writing unit tests is to test the correctness of the functions in the controller (in this context anyway). Since the controller has a dependency on localStorageService, I used an array to mock localStorage, and tested the functions (e.g. addTodo) in the context of this mock. Is this interpretation incorrect?

Comment: No, it's not incorrect. But that's not the only thing you've done. You have also mocked addTodo() and removeTodo(), and replaced them with *fake* methods. Your tests then checks that calling these *fake* methods modifies the fake storage. So, in the end, what does your test tells you about the *real* methods? Nothing, except that they exist. The code of these real methods is never executed in your test. All you execute are the fake methods. Little experiment: Make sure your  unit tests pass. Then replace the code in addTodo() and removeTodo() by `throw 'error';`. Execute the unit tests again.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I was actually mulling over this problem earlier on because I didn't know how to test localStorage - would you recommend that I inject the localStorageService module in the unit test and test it with real data? Or perhaps write a separate set of functions that manipulate the mock storage? Or another solution? I tried the first option but I remember running into some problems before with dependency injection earlier.

Comment: Inject the real localStorageService. Spy on its methods and make them do what you want. Don't spy on anything else. Then call your methods under test. Verify that the scope has the expected state. Verify that the spied localStorageService methods have been called, with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you mean now. I think it'll take a while to get familiar with all the matchers and methods provided for spies to be able to fully exploit the power of spies. Thank you for your help - it's greatly appreciated. :)